# Is it possible to return custom HTML components from TS file in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

TS FILE

```
{
  render: (data) => {
    return "<app-custom-component>Hello World</app-custom-component>";
  }
}
```

HTML FILE

```
<td>
 {{ render(data) }}
</td>
```

I tried `[innerHTML]` but this only works for HTML tags. Custom created components wont appear.

Answer (score 0):

to load component dynamically you can't use innerHtml , you should use [componentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: Could you provide some code? That would be helpful.

Comment: There is a code in the documentation Link I added, it's the best and simplest example. Sometimes, avoiding reading the documentation is not possible ^^

Comment: Reading it right now. Thanks bro.

Comment: No problem, if by reading the documentation there is something you don't understand, don't hesitate to ask again